# Framework method crash in nesting framework

Tags: swift

I have my custom framework, let's call it `TestFramework`, and project, in which I want to include that framework, lets call it `TestProject`.
`TestFramework` use libraries, such as Alamofire, which I added to `TestFramework` using Carthage. When I added `TestFramework` to `TestProject`, the project wouldn't compile until I added Alamofire (and the other libraries that exist in `TestFramework`) using Cocoapods to `TestProject`. This worked until I updated Xcode to version 10. Now, when I try to access libraries methods in `TestFramework`, I get this:

[image]

No error description provided, and I am using latest version of Alamofire.

Comment: How did you add `TestFramework` to `TestProject`?

Comment: By 'AddFiles', added .xcode file, then add it to embeded libraries from products.

Comment: Just a personal word of caution? I would even consider having **Swift** framework dependencies until Swift 5 is GM. (Yeah, I remember DLL Hell.)